# How can I print the double data type as a full number, rather than the truncated number

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large number that I have declared as a double. I would like to print this number as the full number, but whenever I do it only prints the number in truncated (I think) form, as shown below.

```
dim i as double
i = 2^100
debug.print(i)
```

Now the answer shown is `1.267651E+30`.

How do I remove the decimal place and the `e+30` at the end? Following this, I need to convert it to a string, which I can do with a smaller number, but currently, my string just reads `1.267651E+30`.

Comment: No repo.  It prints `1.26765060022823E+30 ` for me, which _is_ the full precision a Double can hold.  If you want to display it without the scientific notation, use `Debug.Print Format(i, "#")`.  this displays `1267650600228230000000000000000`

Comment: Note there is no native data type in VBA that can hold 2^100 as full precision.  Even the higher precision [Decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-nz/office/vba/Language/reference/user-interface-help/decimal-data-type) type overflows for this value

Comment: If you mean to display the value with all the precision of a double precision value, you are doing just that.  If you want to display it with the full precision of the actual number, you need to write or have a routine that can handle greater than Double level precision. `xNumbers 6.0.5,2` a multi-precision add-in still available for download, can do this => `1,267,650,600,228,229,401,496,703,205,376`

Comment: As mentioned by Ron Rosenfeld ..refer .. [learn.microsoft.com page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result#example-using-very-large-numbers)